# Create Custom Block For Umbraco 11 Grid Layout

Tags: package, umbraco, umbraco9

I'm converting Umbraco 8 package to Umbraco 11, but our Umbraco 8 version we used a custom grid layout editor.
According to my knowledge, I can't use it with Umbraco 11 as it has **Block** content. (https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/fundamentals/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-umbraco-property-editors/block-editor/block-grid-editor#1-default-rendering)
So I need to find a way to implement a custom block type with the same features and functionality which we used in Umbraco 8 package. Can anybody guide me on where can I start this or suggest when to explain the documentation?